# Will my SQL Connection remain open after my dictionary is populated

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, connection-string

In the code sample below, will my data context connection stay open once the ListOfLists method is completed?  Do I need to explicitly close it, or will it stay open and be available for other methods.

```
public static Dictionary<int, string > ListOfLists()
        {
            try
            {
                ListDataDataContext db = new ListDataDataContext(GetConnectionString("Master"));

                return db.ListMatchingHeaders
                    .Select(r => new { r.ListRecNum, r.ListName })
                    .ToDictionary(t => t.ListRecNum, t => t.ListName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to database, please check connection and try again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Catching the Exception object like that is bad practice. First, you are swallowing the exception which will make debugging harder later on. Second, you've no exception to do anything with, e.g. `catch(Exception e)`. Third, unless you are actually going to deal with the cause of the exception and fix it, or try and do it again, then you should `throw` the exception, so it is handled further up the call stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still open. You will need to explicitly dispose/close of the connection or it's possible that you might have memory or connection pool problems. I recommend that you wrap your context around a  `using` block.

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> ListOfLists()
{
    try
    {
        using (ListDataDataContext db = new ListDataDataContext(GetConnectionString("Master")))
        {
            return db.ListMatchingHeaders
                .Select(r => new { r.ListRecNum, r.ListName })
                .ToDictionary(t => t.ListRecNum, t => t.ListName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to database, please check connection and try again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return null;
    }
}
```